# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 best solution to change entity's field data type

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm having an issue on changing data type of a field in Dynamics CRM 2011 On Premise deployment.
In my managed solution, name it "Solution 1", I have a custom field in contact entity: "new_usernumber" of type number (int). I want to change it to string as per new client's requirement (for new users they want to add prefix to it).
I can uninstall the solution and deploy the new "fixed" managed solution, but this requires me to delete the value on my custom fields. Is there any better solution for this?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this. If you don't already have data deployed in the instance using the managed solution I recommend deleting it and importing a corrected managed solution file.

There is no supported or unsupported process of changing the data type(or logical name) of a field without data loss. What you will need to do is add the new field and then write a quick update utility to copy the data from the old field to the new field.

[Here is a great article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devkeydet/archive/2012/05/29/deleting-things-from-a-deployed-crm-2011-managed-solution-package.aspx) on exactly how to pull off deleting a field in a managed solution. Note, if you are trying to preserve data you'll need to run the update after the step "Import devkeydetDeleteExample_1_1_HOLDING.zip"

Have fun...this is a pain, but certainly doable!

Comment: Thanks for the article, I did that method at this moment. And it seems writing update utility is inevitable. Hopefully, this conversion can be supported in future development of CRM for simple data type (such as int, decimal to string)

Answer (score 2):

A few months ago I recreated fields in a solution (from *double* to *int*). That was a **huge** mistake. I'm still not sure where things went wrong but they **did** go wrong. Not only did I lose the date. I managed to introduce errors in the meta-layer so our MVP had to sit dear help me get it running again. He wasn't happy. I wasn't happy. The customer wasn't happy (ex-customer today, mostly because of that).

So, my humble advice - don't do that. Declare a new field instead. If you have *usernumber*, keep it but start using *userNumberString* (or *userString*, *userName* etc.). My guess is you'll keep your hair longer that way.

And if you manage to succeed, please do tell. :)

Comment: Atm, we are doing Nicknow's advice. The customer is happy to put  sites to maintenance for a moment, and we are pushing that scenario. We have backed up all db, just in case something bad happened. Let see what's gonna happened after this. Hopefully this gonna run smoothly, finger crossed. EDIT: Btw, thanks for your advice, that's the safer method. Will keep it in mind for alternative solution for this situation :)

Comment: I hope you'll get that working. After all, it **shouldn't** be too complicated. On the other hand, we shouldn't have wars. But we do. :) Consider giving @Nicknow +1, if he was helpful.

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked fine. Sorry, just get back today. Wanna give Nicknow +1 but can't since I'm new here :)

Comment: Don't worry about it. You can do that later or I can ask a friend to vote him up. (I also liked his reply so I got him +1 too.)